# If anyone is interested, here are some ideas for promoting the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I figured out some ways to promote the site that shouldn't be too hard to do. I personally don't have time to do this, but if anyone else is interested in promoting our site...

1. On twitter there's a hashtag called #folklorethursday that has been getting a lot of traffic. It might be interesting to post some of our questions and tag them as #folklorethursday.
2. There are a lot of new podcasts springing up that are dedicated to mythology/folklore type stories. For some reason mythology podcasts seem to be more popular than mythology blogs. It might be worthwhile reaching out to the producers of these podcasts and seeing if they would be interested in promoting the site.

Hope everyone is doing well.